# How to make unit test case for VSCode debug adapter?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

I am working on a debug adapter (with C#) in order to add a new language support to Visual Studio Code, and I want to make some unit test cases and let them run automatically. So is there any framework or extension or anything could help me to achieve this, or I need to make some mock-ups from scratch?

Comment: You can start with learning about Unit test frameworks such as MsTest, NUnit, XUnit etc. Mocking frameworks such as RhinoMocks, Moq, Fakes etc.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thanks. Yes, I could make unit test just treat it as a normal C# project, but I am wondering if there is any framework which is especially used for VSCode debug adapter.